# Is there a way to do planned contrasts after a Kruskal-Wallis test in R?

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test, contrasts

I want to compare three groups: Children, Caregovers and Experts.

I cannot do an ANOVA as my data does not meet the assumptions. Therefore, I need to do a Kruskal-Wallis test.

For Post-hoc I am planning to use contrasts.

First, I only want to compare children and adults (caregovers and experts). Second, I want to compare caregivers and adults.

However, I cannot find information on using contrasts after a Kruskal-Wallis tests. Is there a way to that in R? Or should I just use the Dunn test with correction for multiple comparisons?

Comment: "I cannot do an ANOVA as my data does not meet the assumptions." ... the conclusion doesn't follow from the premise. You don't have to to Kruskal-Wallis, there are many potential options. (a) What sort of variable is your DV? (b) What assumptions are violated and how did you assess it?

Comment: (a) My DV is the mean rank assigned to products with specific product characteristics in a ranking task. People had to rank 16 products (of wich some had the target characteristics) from least liked to most liked product. (b) Especially adults mean rank was not normally distributed, nor had the same variance.

Comment: When the alternative is true,  the mean rank can easily look distinctly non-normal (within groups) and have different variances (across groups). This is not of itself indicative of a problem. If you have a book or other resource suggesting it is, it's likely misleading you about other things. I am somewhat concerned that I may not be correctly understanding your setup though. If an individual is producing 16 ranks, those ranks are not independent (e.g. if you tell me 15 of the ranks, I can tell you the 16th), which suggests that individuals within groups should be treated in a particular way.